# Flutter - how to hide global bottom navigation bar?

Tags: flutter

On one of the pages, nested inside one of bottom navigation bar pages I want to hide the bottom navigation bar, which is set as global. To be clear, I'm talking about this bar:

[image: bottom navigation bar]

I can't just use Navigator.pushNamed because I'm creating viewModel and passing arguments in this way:

```
openConversation(BuildContext context) async {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => ConversationVM(...),
        child: ConversationScreen(
            (...)
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
```

I've tried to set the Scaffold parameter bottomNavigationBar to null, but without effect, I need to resolve that problem somewhere higher.

Nav bar snippet:

```
class NavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'navigation_screen';
 
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _NavigationBarState();
  }
}
 
class _NavigationBarState extends State<NavigationBar> {
  //track the index of our currently selected tab
  int _currentIndex = 0;
 
  //st of widgets that we want to render
  final List<Object> _children = [
    PostedQueries(),
 
  ];
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //body of our scaffold which is the widget that gets displayed between our app bar and bottom navigation bar.
      body: _children[_currentIndex], // new
 
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTabTapped,
        // new
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        // new
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
            label: ('Home'),
          ),
 
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
 
  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: you could wrap the Navigation Bar in a Visibility widget and set `visible` to false based on the index of the page

Comment: @MindStudio  this page on which I want to hide the bar is nested inside one of the navbar pages, so in that case this solution will not  work if I understand it right.

Comment: so you have multiple pages inside one navbar page? In that case you could use a chain of callbacks to send the information whether you are on that page to the global scope to then decide whether it should be visible or not

Comment: @MindStudio Yes, I have a page inside the navbar page. Do you mean that I just should hide that parent navbar page while being in my nested one? That makes sense, I will try, thanks.